# Call code before launching?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in auto-generating some files before the start of my ROS run.   The files will depend on real-time data available at the start of the run.    Is there a nice way to include this in my lanch file ?   Like some tag which funs an executable or python script before loading up the ROS modules?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220430/call-code-before-launching-?/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As noted in the [roslaunch documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node), there are no guarantees on the order that nodes/scripts in launch files are started in. The easiest way to do what you want might be to write a short shell script that first runs the scripts for generating your data and then calls the required ROS launch file afterwards.

/edit To raise awareness for the "hacky way" @dornhege suggests below in comments. An example (creating a folder) is available [here](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_calibration/blob/hydro-devel/pr2_calibration_launch/capture_data/capture_exec_pr2.launch#L68).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-04**:
This sounds like a good solution. There is one slightly hacky way to do this: The param tag allows you to use the output of a command as a parameter. You can create a dummy parameter that just calls your program. Parameters are guaranteed to be set before the launch is started.

**Comment by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on 2015-11-04**:
That hacky way is nice, thanks !